# Unsupported characters in mysql query string

Tags: java, mysql, escaping, special-characters

Where can i find a list of unsupported characters that mysql doesn't allow to use in the query string. I have been using escape characters functionality. Does this still keeps a gap for a possible query failure due to some weird characters?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What problem are you trying to address, what code are you currently using for escaping?

Comment: I am using the escape character funtionality to pad any characters that may break my sql . e.g. ' or " etc. I want to know if there is some illegal characters still left which when added into the where clause lead to my sql string breaking.

Answer (score 1):

You can do before your query

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(query);
```

StringEscapeUtils is from commons-lang library

Comment: "It does not handle the cases of percent (%) or underscore (_) for use in LIKE clauses."

Comment: The code of that method is pretty poor: `return StringUtils.replace(str, "'", "''");`